# how to save pygame camera as video output

Tags: python, video, pygame

I was try this tutorial Stream Webcam Video to PyGame nothing error.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6ijuSmv5N0

and the script like this..

```
import pygame, sys
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0", (640, 480))
cam.start()

while 1:
    image = cam.get_image()
    screen.blit(image, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #save as video output
            sys.exit()
```

But.. in here I have a problem when I want to save that Stream as video output.. like a mp4, 3gp, avi and other.

In this thread `pygame.image.save(img, "image.jpg")` save the output as image.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20502651/3445802

Comment: For me, this recorded my webcam, but not the pygame screen...

Answer (score 2):

Pygame's multimedia output capabilities are severily limited: 
It can only save uncompressed BMP images, and there is no way it can save a video format.

You have to make use of another library which to feed image frames, to render the video - or save frame by frame in a folder, numbering the file names in crescent order, and convert the result to  a video with an utility later.

This project seens to feature a class to call libffmpeg to encode videos, passing frame by frame in a Python call:
https://github.com/kanryu/pipeffmpeg - you will just need a way to convert the pygame Surface object to the expected "frameraw" attribute of
ffmpeg.

https://github.com/kanryu/pipeffmpeg/blob/master/pipeffmpeg.py

Comment: ok sir, thank you for this optionally... 
how about `pymedia` sir?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pygame to capture frames. If you store those to disk, you can then use any software you like to convert those frames to any video format you like.

Modifying your example marginally, this can be done as follows:

```
import pygame, sys, os
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

# Ensure we have somewhere for the frames
try:
    os.makedirs("Snaps")
except OSError:
    pass

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0", (640, 480))
cam.start()

file_num = 0
done_capturing = False

while not done_capturing:
    file_num = file_num + 1
    image = cam.get_image()
    screen.blit(image, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

    # Save every frame
    filename = "Snaps/%04d.png" % file_num
    pygame.image.save(image, filename)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done_capturing = True

# Combine frames to make video
os.system("avconv -r 8 -f image2 -i Snaps/%04d.png -y -qscale 0 -s 640x480 -aspect 4:3 result.avi")
```

I've used this to create stop motion software which can be used with scouts/cubs. The code is also deliberately simple, so a couple of links to these which may be helpful.

Couple of links:

- http://www.sparkslabs.com/camination/
- https://github.com/sparkslabs/camination

Comment: How would you get frames per second rate to match what pygame was showing on screen?

Answer (score -3):

i´m not at home now but my workarround is take the pygame surface and convert to numpy array and write with opencv to mp4 movie.